# How to run edit, reload commands of an ahk file via a windows shortcut or command line?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to be able to launch the script file `.ahk` in edit mode (in sublime), reload, pause etc script via a windows shortcut.

Basically I want some of the following commands, (edit, reload):

[image: Windows Tray AutoHotkey command dialog]

Is there a flag like `/e` or `--edit` `--reload` that is specified in the windows shortcut editor dialog & command line so as to launch the any of above commands:

[image: ahk script shortcut editor dialog]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are built-in commands for both [Reload](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Reload.htm) and [Edit](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Edit.htm)

You can just assign hotkeys to the commands, to execute them directly inside of the code:

```
^!r::Reload  ; Ctrl+Alt+R
^!e::Edit    ; Ctrl+Alt+E
```

Comment: This does the job, but still I would like to know if there are switches/flags that can be specified in the command line or shortcut editor gui

Comment: @appu Have you tried looking at [the documentation of the command-line arguments](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd)? You will find a command there for reloading the script. Editing the script however you can do with a shortcut for the _editor_ you want to use to edit the script.